# Unable to find resource 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:pom:3.4.1' in any of the repositories

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

My maven build emits several INFOs like this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/3.4.1/icu4j-3.4.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:pom:3.4.1' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release)
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/3.4.1/icu4j-3.4.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:pom:3.4.1' in repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/3.4.1/icu4j-3.4.1.pom
```

The build does eventually succeed, but without ever downloading icu4j. Then the next time I build is exactly the same.

I found this [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878309/how-to-suppress-maven-unable-to-find-resource-messages). What I don't understand is how does the build succeed if it really can't find the resource? And if it does find it in the end, why is the resource being downloaded again?

I did find my .m2 folder contains a folder by the name of `com/ibm/icu/icu4j/3.4.4/`, so I'm deducing there is a conflicting dependency somewhere in my pom structure.

How do I resolve this conflict? Again, the project does compile, but it tries to download files on every build, and I'd rather have it compile cleanly.

Comment: In the folder did you see the pom for it?  It may succeed if the JAR exists but not the pom.

Comment: @John V. Both jar & pom exist. Furthermore, I deleted this folder and rebuilt, and the problem persists.

Comment: Hmm have your tried it running debug?  That's odd they both exist and it still is searching for the pom

Answer (score 0):

> The build does eventually succeed, but
>   without ever downloading icu4j

From the message it looks like maven attempts to download the `3.4.1` version of `icu4j` dependency first from `com.springsource.repository.bundles.release`, then `com.springsource.repository.bundles.externa`l and finally from `central` (the default).

There is no `3.4.1` version of `icu4j` in the repository. The project or a dependency in the project has specified this version as a dependency.  Hence maven attempts to download it each time it builds.

As it turns, there is a project dependency on `3.4.4` version of `icu4j`, which gets successfully downloaded.  Maven uses this version (as per dependency resolution rules) and hence the build succeeds.

Running `mvn dependency:tree` should give details of who uses which version of icu4j and make changes appropriately.

Comment: No, when I do N times of "mvn compile" it always prints these messages. I only deleted the repo once as an anlysis step.

Comment: @ripper234. I was misled into believing 3.4.1 version of icu4j gets downloaded from central repo. I guess the INFO message is incomplete. I have updated the answer in light of this.